# Java Quartz default timezone

Tags: java, timezone, quartz-scheduler

I run Tomcat with `-Duser.timezone=UTC`. However Quartz scheduler 2.2.1 seems to run in Europe/Prague which is my OS timezone.

Is there a way to run Quartz in custom timezone or determine which timezone Quartz is using?
If not, is there a way to determine OS timezone programatically?

Answer (score 8):

Quartz by default will use the default system locale and timezone, and it is not programed to pick up the property **user.timezone** you are providing your app. Remember also that this is only applies to a CronTrigger and not a SimpleTrigger.

**If you are using Spring for example:**

```
 <bean id="timeZone" class="java.util.TimeZone" factory-method="getTimeZone">
    <constructor-arg value="GMT" />
</bean>
<bean id="yourTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="yourJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0/1 * * ?" />
    <property name="timeZone" ref="timeZone" />
  </bean>
```

**If you are using plain java:**

```
Trigger yourTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("TRIGGER-ID", "TRIGGER-GROUP")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                         .cronSchedule("0 0 0/1 * * ?")
                         .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")))
                ).build();
```

Comment: CronTriggerBean was removed in spring 4.1

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the XML configuration file, e.g. the `quartz-config.xml` from [*Example To Run Multiple Jobs In Quartz*](http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/) of mkyong, you can configure the timezone in the element `time-zone`:

```xml
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>JobA</name>
        <group>GroupDummy</group>
        <description>This is Job A</description>
        <job-class>com.mkyong.quartz.JobA</job-class>
    </job>
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>dummyTriggerNameA</name>
            <job-name>JobA</job-name>
            <job-group>GroupDummy</job-group>
            <!-- It will run every 5 seconds -->
            <cron-expression>0/5 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
            <time-zone>UTC</time-zone>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

See also [*Java's java.util.TimeZone*](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html) for to see the ID for several timezones.

Comment: I set triggers programmatically. Also i need to set timeZone of quartz itself

Answer (score 2):

You can call [setTimeZone()](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/calendar/BaseCalendar.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) to set the time zone of your choosing for anything in Quartz that inherits [BaseCalendar](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/calendar/BaseCalendar.html).

Java's [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class has a [getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) which should aid in determining OS timezone programmatically.

Comment: Maybe Iam not able to explain my problem properly, my appologies.
My app is running in different timezone than the quartz. I need to set timezone of whole quartz, not of triggers.

TimeZone.getDefault() says app is in UTC, but quartz triggers in Europe/Prague

Comment: In other words: Quartz seems to ingnore `-Duser.timezone=UTC` VM argument

Comment: @Fandic, if you could expound on your architecture/setup/scenario in the original question that would be useful. Regarding setting the timezone for all of quartz, perhaps you could use the custom key/value pairs offered as part of the [Main Config](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigMain) options? Also, you could probably use your -Duser.timezone=UTC JVM arg and enforce it by virtue of TimeZone.setDefault()?